# "contribution to the reaction of micro silica" or "micro silica contribution reaction"

Tags: word-order, attributive-nouns

Which sentence is correct?

> How does **contribution to the reaction of micro silica** change by increasing the amount of water in SCC?

or

> How does **micro silica contribution reaction**, change by increasing the amount of water in SCC?

"micro silica is a powder react by water"

Comment: Would you have a link for the entire sentence? Is micro silica being **added** to the reaction or is the reaction **about** micro silica?

Comment: "How does contribution to the reaction of micro silica change by increasing the amount of water in SCC?"  The reaction is about micro silica.

Comment: @Mehran can you explain what you are doing to the micro silica?  It's not obvious from context.  Please add the additional detail to your question by editing it, rather than commenting.  Thanks!

Comment: Six of one, half a dozen of the other. It simply doesn't matter.

Comment: @Robusto Editting the question (or answer) makes it easier for anyone later reading the thread (if that's what you meant by 6 of 1)...

Comment: @Peter: How would editing the question explain "Six of one, half a dozen of the other"  (a *very* common idiom in English), especially since my second sentence is a literal statement explaining what it means?

Comment: I thought you may be saying that editing the question "doesn't matter" and that leaving his remarks in the comments was basically the same as editting his question. "6 of 1, half dozen of the other" means "there's no difference", so no difference between the remarks being in a comment or in the question, presumably because any later reader would read through both the question and the comments. Editting the question would not explain "6 of 1", but "6 of 1" reflected your feeling of the necessity to edit the question.

Comment: @Peter: I was commenting on the question itself. Had I wished to respond to your comment, I'd have @-mentioned you. BTW, there is only one "t" in "editing" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are trying to ask is

> How does micro silica **contribution change** by increasing the amount of water in a self compacting concrete (SCC) reaction?

meaning you are wondering about the sensitivity of [pozzolanic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pozzolan) and [interactive effects](http://cipremier.com/e107_files/downloads/Papers/100/37/100037011.pdf) of [silicon fume](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silica_fume)  to the compression, bonding, abrasion, and permeability in high performance concrete by varying water density and micro silica amounts.

In which case, neither of your sentences are correct since the word order is not quite right, although the question has been asked [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_does_contribution_to_the_reaction_of_micro_silica_change_by_increasing_the_amount_of_water_in_SCC).

> How does **micro silica** ***contribution reaction***

*contribution reaction* is not an understandable phrase but *reaction contribution* is

> How does **contribution to the reaction of micro silica**

*reaction of micro silica* is also incorrect since the reaction is not micro silica but some other process.

> How does the micro silica **reaction contribution** change...
>   How does **the contribution of micro silica** to the SCC reaction change...

would both ask about the specific reaction's contribution to the overall process which is what I believe you are asking.  This is because the reaction is an overall SCC reaction and  [not a specific micro silica reaction](http://josbrouwers.bwk.tue.nl/publications/Journal105.pdf)